# Inherit Context Configuration and extend locations

Tags: java, spring

I have class for testing database package:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:DatabaseBeanLocations.xml" })
public abstract class AbstractDatabaseTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
...
}
```

For testing another package, eg backend:

```java
public class BackendTest extends AbstractDatabaseTest {
 ...
}
```

So this `BackendTest` class inherits `ContextConfiguration` from `AbstractDatabaseTest`. But I want to add another xml file, eg: `BackendBeansLocations.xml`

One way to do this is to ignore `locations` from superclass:

```
@ContextConfiguration(inheritLocations = false, 
locations = {"classpath:BackendBeansLocations.xml", "classpath:DatabaseBeanLocations.xml" })
public class JobExecutorTest extends AbstractDatabaseTest {
```

But then the `DatabaseBeanLocations.xml` is repeated and this violates DRY rule. Is there a way to avoid this? Inherit locations, but also extend them by adding a new one.

Comment: That should be the default.. Just add the additional files in the `@ContextConfiguration` all the detect ones will be merged into a single context for that test case. At least that should happen...

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that and it didn't work. The beans from `BackendBeansLocations.xml` are missing.

Comment: Which spring version are you using?

Comment: 3.2.5 but, we're planning to use 4.x.x soon :)

Comment: Then it should work... See the doc of [`inheritLocations`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html#inheritLocations()). Make sure you don't set that to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `BackendBeansLocations.xml`, just `<import>` `DatabaseBeanLocations.xml`. Then, in `JobExecutorTest`, just import `classpath:BackendBeansLocations.xml`

This way you'll respect DRY, the inheritance aspcet being just deported from the annotation to the XML file.